# How to Access a UIPickerView Value from Outside the View Controller that Owns the UIPickerView?

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview

I have a picker View declared in the ViewControllerA (in Xib file). This Xib is loaded as a custom cell in ViewControllerB's tableView. If I change the value of Picker View, How can I access this changed value in ViewControllerB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the value of the `UIPickerView` by exposing a property on `ViewControllerA`... If there are set circumstances when `viewControllerB` needs to know the value, under the control of `viewControllerB`, then `viewControllerB` can check the property on `viewControllerA` at those times...

However, perhaps you're asking a more general question about *communication* - with the specific example of `ViewControllerB` needing to know about a change to the `UIPickerView` that's inside `ViewControllerA`...

This article on [Communication Patterns](http://www.objc.io/issues/7-foundation/communication-patterns/) is worth reading. It covers *KVO*, *Notifications*, *Delegation*, *Blocks* and *Target/Action*.

There's a flow-chart near the middle of the article that can help to evaluate what communication strategy to use in a given situation.

From what you've written, it sounds like you could use either KVO (key-value observing) or delegation.

I tend to use delegation in scenarios when one `UIViewContoller` wants to know about changes made in another `UIViewController`, e.g. when `viewControllerC` presents `viewControllerD` - and wants to know about changes made in `viewControllerD`.

In your case, you might use a delegate method along the lines of:

```
- (void)pickerViewValueDidChange:(NSString*)newValue;
```

That *delegate method* would be part of an `@protocol`. Something like:

```
@protocol ABCPickerViewDelegate
- (void)pickerViewValueDidChange:(NSString*)newValue;
@end
```

See [Working with Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH11-SW1) if this is new to you...

`viewControllerB` would conform to that protocol. `viewControllerA` would have a property that conforms to the protocol, something like:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <ABCPickerViewDelegate> pickerDelegate;
```

Then, when the `UIPickerView` value changes within `viewControllerA` - it can call the delegate method... And, `viewControllerB` would then know that the change has occurred and what the value is.

Answer (score 1):

you can get picker value from viewController A on ViewController B using various ways like static getter setter , App delegate class as I mentioned here using appDelegate class
In AppDelegate.h class declare properties with data type on your choice as i take it as NSString

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* pickerValue;
```

Get instance on AppDelegate class in ViewController A and B in viewDidLoad

```
self.appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
```

in picker delegate method set value as

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
  inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

{
    self.appDelegate.pickerValue = self.pickerData[row];

}

In viewController B you can user value from

```
 NSLog(@"ViewControllerB::picker valuer::%@",self.appDelegate.pickerValue);
```

Comment: Thanks,I am going to try it.

Comment: Welcome brother, kindly also upvote to get help with surity for others

Comment: Whilst it's possible to pass the share the value of the `UIPickerView` via the `AppDelegate`, I'm not sure that's the best design. For example, if `viewControllerB` knows about `viewControllerA`, why not just put the property on `viewControllerA`?

Comment: @GavinHope That was what I tried at the very first attempt. But it dint work. I dint know about the other ways, thats y posted the question here.

Comment: @Gavin Hope you are right you can put the property while when we are working in different scenerio like we are switch ViewControllerA to ViewControllerB using seague connection or now we have no need to instatiate ViewControllerA instance in ViewControllerB then Full Allocation of ViewController Instance just to share data is a heavy operation than value Sharing via Delegate, One more thing you can share value via seague also without Property.

Answer (score 0):

**More adaptable way:**
Use NSNotification.

Implement the UIPickerViewDelegate method in ViewControllerA:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView * _Nonnull)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
  //get the data of the picker and save it in the dictionary
  NSMutableDictionary *pickerData =[NSMutableDictionary new]
  [pickerData setValue:[yourArrayForPicker objectAtIndex:row] forKey:@"value"];
    //create and send the notification with the dictionary
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
                 postNotificationName:@"XYYourNotification"
                 object:pickerData];
  }
```

than in ViewControllerB register the listener for the notification:

```
//put this code where you want (maybe in view did load)
    NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [center addObserverForName:@"XYYourNotification"
                        object:nil
                         queue:nil
                    usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification)
    {
//this code will be called when the notification is received
          NSDictionary* info = [notification userInfo];
            NSLog(@"selected :%@", [pickerData valueForKey:@"value"]);
    }];
```